# Spring boot my convert problem string double without e

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Hi my simple project using convert field not converting problem

```
    buildingDTO.setHouseArea(Double.parseDouble(technicalParamDTO.getBuildingSquare()));
```

Output ---> "buildingField":1.0E-4 ,
this is the format i need --> 0.0001

Comment: so, it's not a problem of converting, it's a problem of formatting? Either way, that code doesn't provide output, so I'm not sure why you would expect output from it

Comment: and it has nothing to do with spring or spring-boot right ?

Comment: my project writing spring boot

Comment: If it is case of converting double to string in specific format, try using NumberFormat. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/numberFormat.html

Comment: @anonym just because your project uses spring-boot, doesn't mean the issue is spring-boot related

Answer (score 0):

Try this example as shown here :

```
String input = "0.0001";
double d = Double.parseDouble(input);

System.out.println(d);
System.out.println(String.format("%f",d));
```

Output :

```
1.0E-4
0,000100
```

If you want to replace "," with "." you can try this :

```
System.out.println(String.format(Locale.US, "%f",d));
```

Output :

```
0.000100
```

Comment: NOT WORKING Please add correct code

Comment: 0.000100 this is string not double